# fake askubuntu. Beware

Tags: discussion, support

I found a fake askubuntu i.e. a website that looks exactly like askubuntu but URL is: `http://viyals.com`.

**Beware, if you try to login on such website your username and password maybe stolen.**

Anyway how to report this and to whom?

Comment: Thanks. That one is plainly identical! Looks like a cached version of the site

Comment: NOT AGAIN....... http://askubuntu.greatknow.com/questions is workin asw well!!!! @edwardtorvalds have you reported it here?:http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact